# SVG won't fit browser window, white bar at bottom of window

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, electron

I am trying to have an SVG fit the browser window in an electron window. I have set the width and height of the window to 600 and 840, respectively.

Right now, unless I double click the grey bar at the top of the window to full-size it, there is a white bar that exists at the bottom of the screen. The peculiar part about this problem is that the white bar kind of skips when it appears, as I decrease the dimensions of the window.

I've set the aspect ratio and initial browser size with electron, evidenced by the relevant part of my main.js code.

```
    function createWindow() {
        // Create the browser window.
        mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
          width: 600,
          height: 840
        })

        // and load the index.html of the app.
        mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')
        mainWindow.setAspectRatio(1.37)
```

On the HTML Side, I just have a div, and an SMG.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="X/Electron/smoothiebro1/scripts.js" type="text/JavaScript" /></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container" class="svg-container">
    <img src="X/Electron/smoothiebro1/img/Rectangle 2.svg" id="blenderOutline">
  </div>
  <script>
    // You can also require other files to run in this process
    require('./renderer.js')
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS for my container DIV:

```
html, body { margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; height: 100%;}
svg { position:fixed; top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; border: none; padding: 0; display: block;margin: 0 auto;max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%;}

div{
  border: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

And lastly, here is my "Rectangle" SVG code:

```
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 560.362 769.971" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" >
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        fill: #fff;
        stroke: #777;
        stroke-linejoin: round;
        stroke-width: 10px;
      }

      .cls-2 {
        stroke: none;
      }

      .cls-3 {
        fill: none;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <g id="Rectangle_2" data-name="Rectangle 2" class="cls-1" transform="translate(10 10)">
    <rect class="cls-2" width="540.362" height="749.971" rx="18"/>
    <rect class="cls-3" x="-5" y="-5" width="550.362" height="759.971" rx="23"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work! Perhaps somebody can explain why, but when I made the aspect ratio the reciprocal of 1.37, then it worked.

I got that number from dividing the viewbox height and width by each other.

Comment: Probably because the aspect ratio of an image is normally `width / height`. So it should be `560 / 770` (0.73), not `770 / 560` (1.37).